# Extract only matched value instead of the entire string

Tags: r

Below is the sample of tweets I have extracted which is stored as a dataframe in 'text'

```
(row 1) RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to Cabo SJD $312 nonstop on @AmericanAir for summer travel. airfare
(row 2) RT @TheFlightDeal: Airfare Deal: [AA] New York - Mexico City, Mexico. $270 r/t.
```

Below is the grep function that I have used to extract the string that matches the data I feed the function.
Below is the code:

```
toMatch <- c("Los Angeles", "New York")
matches <- unique(grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"), 
                    text, value=TRUE))
```

This is returning me the entire row if there any matches.

I just want the output to be something like:

```
 (row 1) Los Angeles Los Angeles
 (row 2) New York
```

Also is there a way where I can output the cities in separate cells in the same row?

Comment: `?grep` and `grepl` are for matching. you want one of the other functions documented on that same help page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again using `str_extract_all` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821321/2761575) from [Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983450/psidom). But if you need to list which rows each match is in, then you can try this...

```
toMatch <- c("Los Angeles", "New York")
text = c("(row 1) RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to Cabo #SJD",
         "(row 2) RT @TheFlightDeal: Airfare Deal: [AA] New York - Mexico City, Mexico. $270 r/t.",
         "(row 3) SOME JUNK HERE",
         "(row 4) RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to New York"
)

a <- unlist(sapply(1:length(text), function(i) {
  res <- paste(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(text[i], paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"))), collapse = ' ')
  if (res != "") paste('(row ',i,') ', res, "\n", sep = "")
  else NULL
}))

cat(a)
# (row 1) Los Angeles Los Angeles
# (row 2) New York
# (row 4) Los Angeles Los Angeles New York
```

To get the results in the form of a data frame with each result in a separate column, this works (Note, that this is a generalised approach that works for any number of matches per row - the final data frame will automatically have enough columns to hold the largest number of matches:

```
a <- sapply(1:length(text), function(i) {
  res <- c(i, unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(text[i], paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"))))
  if (length(res) > 1 ) {res
  } else NULL
})
a <- plyr::ldply(a, rbind)
a[] <- lapply(a, as.character)
a[is.na(a)] <- ""
names(a)[1] <- "row"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly @dww. Is there a way where I can output the cities in separate cells in the same row instead of posting all the contents of the row in the same cell?

Comment: Sure. Best method depends whether you need a data frame or a list of vectors. To get a data frame, it's easiest if you know in advance the maximum number of entries any row might have, then you can set up the number of cloumns in advance. Otherwise a little more subtlety is required. Do you know what the maximum number of columns required is? Or does a list work for your purposes?

Comment: Yes I do know. The maximum number of columns I will have will be 5.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks! Also I was further working on the data and I wanted to also extract the dollar value (i.e. the flight price) and paste it on its respective row using paste(ex_dollar(x)) function. I tried sticking it in the code but its just throwing out the dollar values on each row. Where should I include the paste(ex_dollar(x)) in the code Output I have now is : 
    First row ----> 1   1 $234 $270 NA NA   Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX      SJD
    Second row ----> 2   2 $234 $270 NA NA      New York Mexico City

Answer (score 2):

You can try `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package:

```
text = c("(row 1) RT @airfarewatchdog: Los Angeles Los Angeles LAX to Cabo #SJD $312 nonstop on @AmericanAir for summer travel. #airfare",
         "(row 2) RT @TheFlightDeal: Airfare Deal: [AA] New York - Mexico City, Mexico. $270 r/t.")

stringr::str_extract_all(text, paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"))
[[1]]
[1] "Los Angeles" "Los Angeles"

[[2]]
[1] "New York"
```